# Cocoa Check for Updates

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

What is the best way to add a "Check for updates..." functionality to a Cocoa application?
I saw a little framework implementing this but I'm not sure that's the better way.

Should I implement it from scratch?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Sparkle](http://sparkle.andymatuschak.org/) is the most popular way to do this.

There is also the lesser known [update-engine](http://code.google.com/p/update-engine/) which Google is using and developing.

Answer (score 28):

[Sparkle](http://sparkle.andymatuschak.org/) is widely accepted as the best way to do it.

Comment: Agreed. Definitely **don't** write it from scratch. Sparkle has benefited from the experience and feedback of many Cocoa programmers. It's a very straightforward and seamless way to provide in-app updates.