# How to implement a check for update on Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm trying to create an internal app for my company. I want to provide some kind of "automatic update" feature that give the user a message (with install option) once a new version is available. I know that for windows there is a technology named ClickOnce. Is there some kind of standard implementation for mac os x? Should I write it from scratch? If so, how can I start the install process directly from my application? Should I provide a mpkg?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cocoa Check for Updates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466994/cocoa-check-for-updates)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sparkle is probably what you want.  It's used in many apps and is probably the "norm" of actual automatic update nowadays in mac apps other than the app store itself.